# Android Material Date Picker

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using this library https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview as I need a material designed datepicker that allows multiple date selection.

However, I'm running into problems because it uses the threeten backport of LocalDate, rather than java.time.LocalDate.

The datepicker's method for setting dates only accepts the threeten.LocalDate in it's constructor, and I can't see any other method of setting the date other than using the backport. However, I'm using java.time.LocalDate everywhere, and I can't use both (and I'm not changing everything to use the backport!)

Does anyone have a work around, or even an alternative datepicker that I could use?

Comment: Use material date picker - https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android

Comment: @Praveen - I can't because it doesn't allow you to select multiple dates (not a range, but any number of different days)